# iOS app and windows authentication

Tags: iphone, ios, authentication, windows-authentication

We have several internal iOS apps which will be making requests for data to web services which are secured using Windows authentication.

Looking at a method which would be considered best practice for authenticating the requests coming from the app. Is there a way you can use Windows authentication from iOS?

Found the following which look like a couple of options:

- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html
- https://www.centrify.com/mobile/free-mobile-device-security-management.asp

Thank you

Comment: By Windows authentication, do you mean Active Directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a good Objective C library for composing NTLM authenticated requests:

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#ntlm_authentication

Was able to successfully make requests to Windows authenticated IIS hosted web service.

Hope this helps anyone else :)